# Why would I be interviewed for a position if their offer is significantly less than my listed minimum salary?

Tags: interviewing, hiring-process, salary

As is common these days, many job applications require you to list a minimum salary.  I take that as the amount **base salary** I would need in order to meet my job level.

I have a PhD degree in science, and I clearly listed $90,000 as my minimum salary.

I went through the interview process 5 or 6 days; and lo and behold, 5 weeks later I finally get an offer, but at a baffling $60,000.

I'm at the offer stage, but it's likely that they would not match my salary request.

Why bother interviewing me knowing what I specifically stated in the pre employment application? Isn't that the point?

Comment: They may offer you several other things. More vacations, a better work environnement, stock-options, etc. Wait for them to tell you what they can offer you. Plus I don't know which PhD in science you have, but $90k may be a bit much.

Comment: This has become infuriatingly common.

Comment: @Stuart.Sklinar because sometimes having a PhD **is** experience, and it's the sort of experience that you can't easily gain by working an extra 10 years in the field (ie no matter how long you work in a financial firm's front office, you will never touch the value of that guy with a PhD in mathematical finance).

Comment: I agree totally, I just wanted to know if it was the reason of "Just because" like some people with degrees do!

Comment: @JimG. It's irrelevant whether it's an appropriate salary or not.

Comment: Don't worry about why.  They have made you an offer.  Now (1) decide if you want to make a counter-offer; and (2) how much.  Free clue:  Your counter-offer should be much greater than 90K to give them room to negotiate down.

Comment: I just defended my PhD in a strong engineering field.  When I finished my MS I was offered 70K for a job out of the gate, but decided that a PhD was something I wanted.  When you spend 5 years on something, I definitely think it counts as experience.

Comment: I put this question on hold because most of the answers are based primarily on opinion with nothing to back it up. Please see [Good Subjective, Bad Subjective](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/good-subjective-bad-subjective/) for tips on how to edit and reword this question to reopen it. Additionally, (or alternatively), answers could be edited to meet the guidelines in the [help].

Comment: @JohnD. 5 years ago was 2008. The job market hadn't crashed yet (at least if your offer was before september 2008). It was a totally different hiring environment. In the last 5 years, in general, the employers are offering less because they have more people to choose from. Especially, new grads with no on-the-job experience. As for 5 years counts as experience, only if that experience is directly relevant to the job you are applying for. And in all but exceptional cases, it doesn't count nearly as much as 5 years on the job experience.

Answer (score 35):

Possibilities:

- They made a mistake.
- They think that you will be willing to settle for a lower figure.
- You were interviewed because they needed to do X interviews, but you accidentally won. Now after you reject their offer they will take the 2nd place candidate.
- You were interviewed because they needed to do X interviews, the number one candidate turned them down.
- They thought they could pay more, but the new budget limits what they can pay.
- You were the only candidate that passed the initial screen.
- They will be offering you non-salary items that they haven't disclosed yet.

Comment: They want you to reject the offer so they can hire a foreign worker on a particular type of visa that requires them to prove that they tried to hire and couldn't find a candidate who will accept their offer.

Comment: Another possibility is that they might have paid 90k, but now they have interviewed you they think your skill level is only worth 60k.

Comment: I'm going to bet that @HLGEM is correct, but another possibility is that they would *prefer* you, but they need to reset the pay for the opening with their HR Department.  They need to show HR that qualified people cost more than they wish were the case.  Still, HLGEM is (sadly) probably right.